# How to generate 5 different random numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I have tried to generate 5 different random numbers in the for loop to generate the 5 images, but the 5 random numbers are generated exactly the same!
    var numberOfFaces = 5;

```
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {

    //create image

    var img = document.createElement('img');

    img.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";

    var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500 - (100 * i));

    var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500 - 100 * i);

    img.style.top = random1;

    img.style.left = random2;

    document.body.appendChild(img);

}
```

Comment: tip: if you don't mind getting integers in a power-of-256 range instead of floats, you can use [crypto.getRandomValues(typedArray)](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#Crypto-method-getRandomValues) to get a large number of truly random values faster than Math.random.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not that the random numbers aren't random, but to set the css values you'll need a unit as well, like pixels, percentage etc.

```
img.style.top = random1 + 'px';
img.style.left = random2 + 'px';
```

And for those CSS values to take effect, the elements have to have a position other than `static`

```
img.style.position = 'absolute';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/b6jpt2kh/)

Comment: It's not really stupid, adding `px` is something all of us forget at times, especially since jQuery and other libraries abstract that away, and the CSS positioning thing is asked almost daily and is a common mistake.

Comment: @Computerlucaworld no question is stupid! Stack overflow was created for these kind of questions, no worries!

Answer (score 1):

(Sir check your random number generation statement)

There are some examples on the [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) Center page:

```
/**
* Returns a random number between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)
*/
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

/**
* Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive)
* Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
*/
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```